# Environmental variables from .env file are not loaded when jest test is launched in debug mode on chrome dev tools

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, dotenv

I work on a vue.js app, which is tested with jest. To debug those tests I used this command `node --inspect-brk node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand --config test/jest.config.js` and everything worked fine in chrome dev tools.

Later we introduced some environmental variables to the project to set some values using dotenv (variables can be accessed through process.env), tests also run fine, but when the debugger is attached, environmental variable values are not read from `.env` file.

How to run/debug jest tests in chrome dev tools on a vue.js project that uses environmental variables described in `.env` file, accessed through `process.env`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exporting .env file contents helped. Ran such command `export $((cat .env ; cat .test.env)| grep -v "^#" | xargs) && node --inspect-brk node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand --config test/jest.config.js`, the exported .env variables got saved and on later runs it was enough to run just the test launching script `node --inspect-brk node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand --config test/jest.config.js`